# How do you subtract two lists in Python 3. I tried using map and numpy, but it did not work in google colaboratory, the platform in which i run in

Tags: python

This is my code so far:

```
input1 = "abcdef"
input2 = "zyxw"
output1 = []
output2 = []
for character in input1:
      number = ord(character) - 96
      output1.append(number)
for character in input2:
      number = ord(character) - 96
      output2.append(number)
map_object = map(operator.sub, output1, output2)
subtracted_list = list[map_object]
print[subtracted_list]
```

Here I am trying convert each input into numerical values and subtract input1 from input2. I got the numerical values in two lists and now i need to subtract them. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to define how your code will handle the case of the two lists being of different lengths.  The likely choices are to truncate the longer list, or pad the shorter list with zeros.

Comment: The code you posted almost works. To call a function such as `list()` and `print()`, use `()`, not `[]`.  Eg `subtracted_list = list(map_object)` and `print(subtracted_list)`. You also need `import operator` at the beginning. With these three changes you code worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. Use parentheses to call a function, not brackets. I'm voting to close this question since it's basically a typo. In the future please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `itertools.starmap` in one line. *(make sure you import it as well as `operator.sub`)*

```
list(starmap(sub, zip(map(ord, input1), map(ord, input2)])))
```

If you want to make you don't lose any characters due to irregular length strings use `itertools.zip_longest` and be sure to sort them by length.

```
list(starmap(sub, zip_longest(*sorted(map(list, [map(ord, input1), map(ord, input2)]), key=len), fillvalue=0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) (and/or [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=zip_longest#itertools.zip_longest) from the `itertools` module) can do this for you.

As jasonharper mentioned in their comment, how your code needs to handle lists of different lengths will determine which of the two you should use:

- If you want to stop when the *shortest* list ends, use `zip`
- If you want to continue until you've exhausted the *longest* list, use `zip_longest`. Don't forget to specify a `fillvalue` (default is None)

Finally, to answer your question, you can create the result with a list comprehension:

```
input1 = "abcdef"
input2 = "zyxw"

# Convert to character codes
ord1 = [ord(c) - 96 for c in input1]
ord2 = [ord(c) - 96 for c in input2]

# Subtract value pairs
subbed = [a - b for a, b in zip(ord1, ord2)]
```

where subbed (in this case) is `[-25, -23, -21, -19]`